# Removed header menu but space remains?

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have a centralised logoo with the menu underneath, I 'hid' the menu links but now the space remains where they where, leaving an awkward 20/25px space underneath my logo.

I could put padding-top on my logo to even it out but I don't think that's a very future-proof way to do it (mess with different screen sizes).

Can anyone offer a simple solution? Thanks

Comment: We need to see your code. Give us a [mcve] of the issue please.

Comment: Hi Michael, this was done through the divi theme's interface. There is no code to provide as far as I can tell. Thanks

Comment: Is your site online anywhere for us to see?

Comment: Problem solved, Michael, thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How are you hiding the menu links?

**Try setting "display:none" to hide and set "display:block" to show.**

If you are trying to hide the links using "visibility:hidden" it means the tag would not be visible, but space will be allocated for it on the page.

Please post your code for more details if this doesn't help.

Comment: Hi Shruti, I'm not entirely sure how to implement this. I changed it from my theme's interface on wordpress. If I inspect the element of the menu and use it's tag to 'display:none', that should work yeah?Thanks

Comment: @jamie - Can you make changes to the code through the interface. If yes,then please try setting the display property to none  of the menu element.

Comment: That worked :) Turns out I had turned off the menu by using 'visibility: hidden' in CSS. Not a good idea! Thanks Shruti